# Docker says unknown operand golang alpine

Tags: docker, go

I have the following docker image:

```
FROM golang:1.16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN go mod init auto-rebase

RUN go build

ENV PROJECT=""

CMD [ "echo", $PROJECT ]
```

After building and runnign:

```bash
docker build -t marge-auto-rebase .
docker run -e PROJECT=37473816 --rm -it marge-auto-rebase
```

I get the following error:

> sh: 37473816: unknown operand

This runs just fine outside docker, what is the issue here? It seems like this is something related to alpine?

Comment: As I understand, you can follow this thread https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5509#issuecomment-42173047

Comment: Assuming you want the value of the environment variable to be printed, you need to remove the broken JSON-array syntax so that it's a [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) `CMD`; `CMD echo $PROJECT`.  Since what you have here isn't actually a JSON array, Docker runs it through a shell anyways, which produces the error you see.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be a `sh` issue. I don't have explanations for this behavior. I made it work by rewriting your `CMD` instruction like so:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $PROJECT"]
```